# How to merge segmented webvtt subtitle files and output a single file?

Tags: ffmpeg, webvtt, srt, vtt

How to merge a segmented webvtt subtitle file and output a single file?,
m3u8 looks like this example:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#USP-X-TIMESTAMP-MAP:MPEGTS=900000,LOCAL=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-1.webvtt
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-2.webvtt
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-3.webvtt
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-4.webvtt
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-5.webvtt
#EXTINF:4, no desc
0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-6.webvtt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I noticed that each segment is not synchronized/cued against total playing time, but against the individual ts segments.
If ffmpeg could be used to do this, what magic input do i need to give it?

A single correctly cued vtt or srt file is what i want.

I have a great appetite and don't like chunks, lol!

Thanks for any replies you lovely people!

---

With this i get a merged vtt file, but the cues are all wrong:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://cmoreseusphlsvod60.akamaized.net/vod/bea44/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).ism/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000.m3u8" -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_format webvtt -scodec copy out-%05d.vtt
```

Each segment is not synchronized/cued against total playing time, but against the individual ts segments.
Example output of above command:

```
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:03.040
Du har aktier i ett företag
som saknar framtid.

00:00.000 --> 00:03.280
De vill ha aktierna.
Du känner dem inte, Olga.

00:00.000 --> 00:01.720
De som får Kastrups aktier vinner.
```

Cues all start like this which isn't very helpfull: **00:00.000**

Some segments contains no cues, like segment 15 for example:
https://cmoreseusphlsvod60.akamaized.net/vod/bea44/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).ism/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP)-textstream_swe=2000-15.webvtt

> "A WebVTT Segment MAY    contain no cues; this indicates that no
>   subtitles are to be displayed    during that period."

Comment: Do you know the duration of each segment?

Comment: Yes, 4 seconds. I think it says so above.  here's how the m3u8 looks like that has all the elements:    
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/npDzTJMe).    
Here's the full url to the stream    [https://lbs-usp-hls-vod.cmore.se/vod/bea44/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).ism/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).m3u8](https://lbs-usp-hls-vod.cmore.se/vod/bea44/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).ism/0ghzi1b2cz5(11792107_ISMUSP).m3u8)

Comment: @Dobbelina Did you have any luck with solving this?

Comment: Answer is no, but i buried this puppy a long time ago.  Seems like a tricky issue to solve.

Comment: ffmpeg -y -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -allowed_extensions ALL -i subtitle_playlist.m3u8 -c copy -f webvtt merged_segments.vtt